# Xcode - Is there a way to disable the Iphone from charging?

Tags: iphone, xcode, battery

I know its a long shot, but is there a way (programitically) to stop the phone from charging when it is connected to charger?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: You can try unplugging it from the charger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can monitor the battery’s status using a couple of methods on UIDevice, but it’s astronomically unlikely there will ever be an API to prevent charging.